# Can any one help me to create admin payment method in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

If any can help me to create extension for admin payment method while creating a order from admin and which should have all default payment methods in magento 2

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of free extension you can take reference from any.

https://github.com/Joshua29LK/magento-2-admin-payment-method

please check above link.

note: I know adding a link as a answer is not good practice

Comment: Thank you for your help. But i need all default payment methods in admin without enabled it.